# Does Docker use swapfile by default?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, filesystems

I'm using docker compose v3. I manually added swapfile to Linux.

Would Docker use it by default on next system start?

Should i manually define swap in docker compose yml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Linux containers use Linux Host OS resources, so the swap file is used too.